# How is the CQFP64 package supposed to be soldered?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, soldering, packages

I am currently designing a PCB containing an ATmegaS128 with the CQFP64 package (see picture below and page 460 of [its datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/atmegas128_ds.pdf)), but I do not know how it can be soldered. Can the golden frame and ceramic slab be removed before soldering, or should the pins be cut and bent onto the PCB?

Information on this kind of package seems quite sparse, and I could not find any answer.

[image: ATmegaS128]

Comment: Did you look for soldering information for this package from Atmel?

Comment: Since you're designing for some sort of a space or rad-hard environment, I suggest you get training for this. There's way more to know than merely how to support this package on your PCB. There are lots of other components that may require special treatment of some sort, etc. This sort of a thing should generally not be attempted without training, as only the people who actually work in those environments will have all the know-how in one place. There isn't any single book you could buy to learn the stuff. And you will need manufacturer engineering support. Lots of it.

Comment: Sorry for the rant, but... why would anyone even consider fricken _Atmel_ for such an environment??? They always had a nasty reputation for poor EMC characteristics even in normal applications. Plus the core is awfully inefficient. Is it a hobbyist space rocket?

Comment: I *think* this is how the pins are assembled in most ICs; the factory just does the bending and cutting for you. I could easily be wrong though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's really not much documentation on the CQFP64.  I found a document with all the [dimensions of many CQFP variants](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa025/snoa025.pdf), but I couldn't find anything about actually using them.

I did find an example of the ATmega chip you were looking at in a description of an [evaluation board](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/Atmel-41077A-Aero-Hardware-Tools-for-ATmegaS128.pdf) for the ATmegaS128.

[image]

The pins appear to have been cut and bent before soldering.

From the picture you originally posted, the soldered chip on the evaluation board, and the drawings in the CQFP dimension document, I'd say the frame is removable - rather, the chip sits in the frame for shipping and handling.

Given the similarity to the original [Flatpack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatpack_(electronics)) SMD packages, I'd say that you are intended to cut the pins to length before installing the ICs.

---

I would think that if you are using a space rated part, you'd contact Microchip directly.  It is likely that they have documentation besides what is publicly available.  It is also likely that they will have engineers who can advise you on how best to make use of such specialty parts.

Comment: This is common procedure for metal-ceramic cases, called trimming and forming, "frame" is a carrier. Most likely, officials will offer you a special (expensive) tool for this. If you are not going to mass-produce, it is easier to do this by hands with appropriate templates. As, i guess, you are making cosmic electronics, there should be local instructions about how to produce boards in details, this is not as simple as amateur ones. Local regulations is a cause of not forming IC leads on factory.

Answer (score 4):

> Can the golden frame and ceramic slab be removed before soldering, or should the pins be cut and bent onto the PCB?

Normally no. Flip it over and it'll be ready to be surface-mounted (Atmel print should face to the board).

Can be either soldered or socketed.

NOTE: That frame is a support for excessive vibration. If the application doesn't have to be vibration-proof then the frame can be removed and the pins can be trimmed.

Answer (score 1):

[This document](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/129908-ac174-assembly-instructions-for-cqfp-packages-smt-on-pcb-app-note) explains how to mount CQFP packages, and includes photographs showing the various stages. They recommend using lead forming tools by [Fancort Inc](https://fancort.com/pages/lead-forming-home) to trim and form the pins for the particular application.